# Mobile API and params verification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing my first mobile API an I can't find the best way to validate params, entities etc.

Now I do somethig like this `before_filter :verify_adding, :only => :add` and verify every param and entity in this verify methods. It doesn't look like elegant solution.

Please, suggest the best way to do such verifications

Answer (score 1):

It's not the Rails way of validating input data.

Mostly you build an object using `params` and call the `valid?` function.

Because validation is a cross cutting concern which means that it will happen in different layers of your application, so it will be a good practice to put it somewhere so that you'd be able to call it somewhere else.

If your objects are ActiveRecord objects then the best place and way of validation is adding validation rules to your domain object which is an ActiveRecord derived object.

If not you can add [ActiveModel](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html) modules to your domain object and use validation rules just like a regular rails app.

Comment: but I need to return different codes for different request errors. Hw can I do that from ActiveRecord validation

Comment: you can decide on `errors` attribute of object. look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-errors